What do the conjugations of いる mean?
I know that いる means "need" (as in "I need something").
And some of the conjugations make sense:
いります - need (something)
いりません - don't need (something)
いりました - needed (something)
いりませんでした - did not need (something)
But I can't make sense of some of the other conjugations, namely:
If ...たい = want to (do something)
=> いりたい = want to need (something)?
If ...たくない = do not want to (do something)
=> いりたくない = do not want to need (something)?
If ...ましょう = let's (do something) or we should (do something)
=> いりましょう = let's need (something) or we should need (something)?

I don’t know about いる specifically, but I wouldn’t be surprised if some verbs have conjugations that are grammatically valid but don’t really make sense and are therefore unused in practice.

Unless in wordplay, those forms make no sense to me. A random example: 「別の人に頼むので追加は要りません」「要れよ」「要れってなんですか、要れって」 https://syosetu.org/novel/251999/26.html

There are rules for how to modify verbs to express the ideas you wish to express.  These rules ignore the semantics of the word.  But in theory, these different forms are possible.
I would worry less about what forms you can create might mean than understanding these forms when you hear them.
This is really not all that different from English.  If you want to express a certain idea: desire, ability, necessity,... there are simple rules.  For desire you use the word "want" and the infinitive of the verb.  You can apply this rule to any verb you wish.  That doesn't mean the expression will mean anything particularly meaningful.  But, you recognize it when you hear it.
So, yes, if you want to say something like I want to need that book, as strange as that may sound you can also express that in Japanese, そのほんがいりたい.  Why someone would ever say something like this, I don't know.  But, perhaps you are required for some reason to purchase a particular book; it's necessary (for your job, for school, for some reason).  But you wish you didn't have to purchase the book.  Perhaps then, その本はいりたくない could make sense.
Suppose someone offers John their services as an excellent carpenter.  But John doesn't need a carpenter.  Perhaps John, however, really likes their work.  I could conceive of John perhaps saying, "I want to need your service, but they’re not needed."
